# Webpack dev server: Proxy external server and replace inline script and styling

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Due to technical limitations outside my control I need to setup a webpack project to serve pages from an external webserver.
Certain pages on the external server include an inline script and inline style.

My current webpack setup generates a `bundle.js` and a `bundle.css` which are supposed to replace the contents of these tags.

Is there a way to setup webpack dev server with perhaps some kind of filter function which receives the response from the proxied server and is able to inject the bundles into the html document before serving it?

(Automatically reloading the page when local changes occur is optional but would be nice.)

E.g.:

bundle.js is:

```js
console.log("Coconut")
```

bundle.css is:

```css
body {background-color: red;}
```

example.com/foobar serves:

```html
<html>
....
  <script src="example.com/vendor/jquery.js"></script> <!-- some assets served by the external server -->

  <style> body {background-color: green;} </style>
  <script> console.log("Apple") </script>
....
</html>
```

The desired result served by the webpack dev server
localhost:8080/foobar

```html
<html>
....
  <script src="localhost:8080/vendor/jquery.js"></script> <!-- webpack should proxy this script as normal -->

  <style> body {background-color: red;} </style>
  <script> console.log("Coconut") </script>
....
</html>
```

---

Currently my minimal webpack setup looks like this:

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        project_name: ["./src/js/index.js", "./src/css/index.scss"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        clean: true
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].bundle.css",
    })],
    externals: {
        jquery: "jQuery"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            implementation: require("sass"),
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        devMiddleware: {
            index: false,
        },
        proxy: {
            target: "https://www.example.com/",
            changeOrigin: true,
            context: () => true,
        }
    }
};
```